# Use Chebyshev’s inequality to choose $n$ such that $P(\bar{X} > 4) > 0.9$

Tags: probability, inequality

Use Chebyshev’s inequality to choose n such that $$ P(\bar{X_n} > 4) > 0.9 $$
where
$$ E[\bar{X_n}] = 5 \ \ \ \ \ Var[\bar{X_n}] = \frac{4}{n} $$

The problem I am having when using Chebyshev's inequality 
$$ P(|Y-\mu| > \epsilon ) \leq \frac{\sigma^{2}}{\epsilon^{2}}, \ \ \epsilon> 0$$

is that and when trying to manipulate this formula, I am always getting $$ 
P(\bar{X_n} - 5 > -1)\ \ where\ \ \epsilon < 0 $$ and so i can't use Chebshev's Inequality since not all the conditions have been satisfied.

How am I able to use the inequality?

Comment: Use $P(\bar{X_n} > 4)>1-P(|\bar{X_n}-5| > 1)$.

Comment: If you have no idea to get an upper bound on $P(|\bar X|>1)$ then let me suggest to reread your lecture notes (or the title of your own post).

Comment: wait just realised how to do it, thanks for your input

Comment: A one-sided version of  Chebyshev’s inequality could give give you a slightly smaller $n$, but assuming $\bar{X_n}$ stands for the sample mean of $n$ i.i.d. random variables, it would still be too high